# What is the error in this query. Help Appreciated

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]."'WHERE email =$email'".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'AND password = $pw'".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your query will be,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($email, $_POST['email'])."' AND password = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($pwd,$_POST['password'])."'";
```

Comment: @DestinatioN Why did you add SYNTAX ERRORS to the answer?!

Answer (score 1):

OR maybe before creating an query you should go like this

```
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
  $pw = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$pw'";
```